# how to transpose dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, transpose

I've got a dataframe (result from groupby par "nr")

```
id  lap  nr  time
 1    1   2    10
 4    2   2   100
```

I need to rearrange this dataframe to folowing format

```
nr lap1 time1 lap2 time2
 2    1    10    2    100
```

Any Idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of this as a [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-and-pivot-tables). If your DataFrame had an extra column called, say, `colnum`:

```
   lap  nr  time  colnum
0    1   2    10       1
1    2   2   100       2
```

then

```
df.pivot(index='nr', columns='colnum')
```

moves the `nr` column values into the row index, and the `colnum` column values into the column index:

```
       lap    time     
colnum   1  2    1    2
nr                     
2        1  2   10  100
```

This is basically the desired result. All we need to do is fix up the column labels:

```
df.columns = ['{}{}'.format(col, num) for col,num in df.columns]
```

---

Thus,
    import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 4], 'lap': [1, 2], 'nr': [2, 2], 'time': [10, 100]})
df['colnum'] = df.groupby('nr').cumcount()+1
df = df[['lap','nr','time','colnum']]
df = df.pivot(index='nr', columns='colnum')
df.columns = ['{}{}'.format(col, num) for col,num in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
```

yields

```
   nr  lap1  lap2  time1  time2
0   2     1     2     10    100
```

Comment: Some issue with adding "colnum": SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df['colnum'] = df.groupby('nr').cumcount()+1

Comment: In your real code are you using double indexing, such as `df[...]['colnum'] = ...` or is it exactly `df['colnum'] = df.groupby('nr').cumcount()+1`? If you are using the former, then it is the [double (aka "chained") indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-the-assignment-when-using-chained-indexing-fail) which is causing the warning. If you are using the latter, then ... I'm mystified.

Comment: my real code, i need somehow to copy the name from the source dataframe to the result (last line) http://pastebin.com/9JB9VgVN

Comment: My mistake. `df = df[['lap','nr','time']]` followed by `df['colnum'] = df.groupby('nr').cumcount()+1` is tantamount to chained indexing. The solution is to reverse the order of these two lines. I've edited the post above to show what I mean.

Comment: I have to study why I have to first add colnum and than make groupby, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the `df`, `df[['lap','nr','time']]` may return a view or a copy. If it's a copy, then `df[[...]]['colnum'] = ...` has no effect on `df` because only the copy, `df[[...]]` is modified. In our case, this is a mute point since we are assigning `df = df[...]` so modifying a view or copy would return the same result. Nevertheless Pandas warns about chained indexing whenever it is detected.  See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-the-assignment-when-using-chained-indexing-fail for more info.